# Having issue while parsing Json volley request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

this is my request code ,please help me to parse it correctly. I want all the options for each particular question but I am getting only one option .can anyone solve it. I have attached SS of my data format.[image]

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
            "http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/mobileData/request.php?request=QuizStart&module=handShake&title=does-your-crush-like-you-girls-only_1",
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // ArrayList<Data> listData = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {    

                        try {    
                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("quiz");
                           // JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(0);
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject currentArray = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                DataQuestions movie = new DataQuestions();
                                movie.setQuestion(currentArray.getString("question"));
                                String question = currentArray.getString("question");
                                System.out.println("question----------" + question);
                                movie.setQuesImage(currentArray.getString("QuesImage"));
                                String image = currentArray.getString("QuesImage");
                                System.out.println("QuesImage----------" + image);    

                                 JSONArray keys= currentArray.getJSONArray("keys");
                                for(int j =0;j<keys.length();j++){
                                    JSONObject keyobject = keys.getJSONObject(j);

                                    movie.setOption(keyobject.getString("option"));}    

                                /*String key = null;

                                if(keys.getJSONObject("option")) {

                                    key = keys.getString("option");
                                }
                                movie.setOption(key);*/   

                               /* JSONArray jsonArray1 = (jsonObject.getJSONArray("keys"));
                                int numberOfItemsInResp = jsonArray1.length();
                                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfItemsInResp; j++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                    DataQuestions options = new DataQuestions();
                                    //   movie = new DataQuestions();

                                    options.setOption(jsonObject2.getString("option"));
                                    String optios = jsonObject2.getString("option");
                                    System.out.println("option----------" + options);
                                    // JSONArray jsonArray1 = (response.getJSONArray("keys"));*/

                                    movieList.add(movie);
                                }    
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }    
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //  hidePDialog();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);    
}
```

Comment: Use Gson and create class according to your response.

Comment: And you can use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to create classes from JSON instantly

Comment: @SANAT is right, by using json data create model classes and use Gson library avoid writing heavy code. No need to worry about looping and adding data.

Comment: thank you 
 
@SANAT

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your data format, copy and paste or type the actual data into the post directly.

Comment: @VinceBowdren give the answer if you can

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you use a single object in second for loop. You should to define keys object and stored within arraylist in main object. Like this

```
public class Quiz {
    String quizId;
    String QuesImage;
    String question;
    String questionId;
    String Type;
    int index;
    ArrayList<Keys> keysList;

}

public class Keys{
    String answerId;
    String option;
    String AnsImage;
}
```

and parse it

```
JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("quiz");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

    Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
    quiz.QuesImage = jsonObj.getString("QuesImage");
    quiz.question = jsonObj.getString("question");
    quiz.questionId = jsonObj.getString("questionId");
    quiz.Type = jsonObj.getString("Type");
    quiz.index = jsonObj.getInt("index");

    JSONArray keys = jsonObj.getJSONArray("keys");
    for (int j = 0; j < keys.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject keysObj = keys.getJSONObject(j);

        Keys keys = new Keys();
        keys.answerId = keysObj.getString("answerId");
        keys.option = keysObj.getString("option");
        keys.AnsImage = keysObj.getString("AnsImage");

        quiz.keysList.add(keys);
    }
}
```